# how to use passwordless user in Ansible

Tags: ansible, password-less

We have a machine that use a password-less user to run few things.
Our applicative user was configure to support sudo on that machine, so I can run "sudo su - " and became that user, without specifying password. (This is configured in the sudores file)

The problem is how to configure ansible that run playbooks using our applicative user, and it needs to became the passwordless user.

I tried to configure it like this-
    become: yes
    become_method: sudo
    become_user: 
But I get- "sudo: a password is required"

If I switch the method to "su" I get- ""Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt:"

Any idea? I understand that perhaps the become_flags can help, but have not saw much documentation on it

Comment: Please paste here the Ansible code and your sudoers file (relevant section is enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [become guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html), you have to either set the `ansible_become_password`, preferably [using vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vault.html#playbooks-vault), or as you stated set password-less sudo for your user.

You can do that by editing your sudoers file, and setting appropriate directives. You typically edit the file with the command visudo. An example if your user is member of sudo group:

```
%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

According to your setup this may need some variation.

Comment: If the user does not have a password, what value should I use for the ansible_become_password ?  The sudoers file was updated, as I worte- I can from command line of that user do "sudo su - <password less user>" and it works

Comment: Oh sorry I have read your question too fast... What is your ansible user? Can you give relevant sudoers configuration?

Comment: We have a user that we use for applications that we use for all our systems, but on some systems we need to use different users.  How can the "ansible_become_password" help us? Is it suppose to be the password of the application user that connect to the host and try to switch to the other user ?

Comment: Alright, now we have multiple questions to answer ^^. First, what is the user that ansible uses to connect to your remote systems? It is setup with the configuration variable `ansible_user`. We need to first answer that because it is this user that needs to become your application's user.

Comment: Yes, we have this user (Lets call usera) that we use to connect to the remote machine and is configured as ansible_user, and we have user (lets call userb) that does not have a password, but is required to run few commands. actually- I noticed that when I assign the ansible_become_password the value of usera password, I pass the original failure, now I get error that I don't have permissions to run "echo" as userb

Comment: Hi,

I now did the following changes in configuration-
1) Set the ansible_become_password to be the password of user A (The one that log in to the machine, and swtich to User B, who does not have password)
2) I modified the become_method from su to sudo

Now I get different error- (looks like it can now become that user, with limitations)
Sorry, user **** is not allowed to execute '/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-rnzgycwpjfficcehtpnchwbdfiovgnqm; /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1584873208.7-268897747635188/command.py' as <User B name> on <Host>

Any idea why it fails?

Comment: Can you provide relevant section of your sudoers file?

Comment: Hi, it is quite complicated and security reasons prevents me to display all, but basically it will look like something like this-
<Correct User name- User A>      <COnfiguration name>=(root)     NOPASSWD: <Name thae contains permission for the command I am trying to do> 
The weird thing is that I don't try to perform "echo" but the error in ansible is because I don't have permissions to run echo as User B

Comment: Thanks. As userA must be allowed to impersonnate userB you should not have root in the line but userB, so basically something like that : userA ALL=(userB) NOPASSWD: ALL The echo is just a test that the sudo works.

Comment: Hi, I tested it, and now it pass, but it fails in the activation of the command, since UserA does not have the PATH of User B, some of the shared libraries are missing.  But I will accept the answer and open new question for it

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my asnwer to sum everything up. Did you post your new question? What does your playbook do? If your task is a command/shell task for example you can try to set the environment, either in the command itself or with environment parameters or the task. In the command line it would look like `PATH=.... LD_LIBRARY_PATH=... command parameters`. You could also explicitly source a .profile/.bashrc... before your command : `source path/to/.profile && command parameters`

Comment: Thanks, I did not open a new question, just implemented the same solution you proposed- source $HOME/.profile